# JAXB (JAX-WS): empty tag when value is null

Tags: java, soap, jaxb

I have soap web service. When I perform request to it with null parameter, on server I receive not null parameter. 
There is an empty tag in request: `<SomeValue></SomeValue>`, so this interpreting like not null but empty object, and I don't know why, because according to JSR 222 (I'm using java 1.6), null value is mapping to soap message by jaxb not like an empty tag, but like no tag at all. 
In wsdl is marked that this param can be null.
This parameter is represented by class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "SomeValue")
public class SomeValue {

    @XmlElement(name = "list", nillable = true)
    protected List<SomeElement> list;

    public List<SomeElement> getList() {
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<SomeElement>();
        }
        return this.list;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that your empty element values resolve to some translation of an empty value and that null is only resolved by omitting that element in the request altogether.